# How to check destructor has been called in thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using boost to start a thread and the thread function is a member function of my class just like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void ThreadFunc();
    void StartThread() {
        worker_thread_ = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(
        new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::ThreadFunc, this)));
    }
};
```

I will access some member variables in `ThreadFunc`:

```
while (!stop) {    
    Sleep(1000);  // here will be some block operations
    auto it = this->list.begin();
    if (it != this->list.end())
        ...
}
```

I can not wait forever for thread return, so I set timeout:

```
stop = true;
worker_thread_->interrupt();
worker_thread_->timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout_ms));
```

After timeout, I will delete this `MyClass` pointer. Here will be a problem, the `ThreadFunc` hasn't return, it will have chances to access `this` and its member variables. In my case, the iterator will be invalid and `it != this->list.end()` will be true, so my program will crash if using invalid iterator.

My question is how to avoid it ? Or how to check whether `this` is valid or member variables is valid ? Or could I set some flags to tell `ThreadFunc` the destructor has been called ?

Comment: Why would you delete `MyClass` if its still in use? Seems like bad design. If you need the thread to still be semi-operable without `MyClass` then it shouldn't be a member. You'll need to have synchronization around what might be stolen out from under you. Probably best to use an atomic shared `MyClass` pointer. And have `ThreadFunc` be a free function that takes it in as a parameter.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yes, I think it's a bad design, shared pointer seems good.

Comment: You probably need to synchronize access to data shared between threads.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I had add lock to synchronize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possible solutions. One is to use a `shared_ptr` to the class and let the thread hold its own `shared_ptr` to the class. That way, the object will automatically get destroyed only when both threads are done with it.

Comment: Thanks, shared_ptr will be enough to solve my problem. By the way, how a about the solution without boost ?

Comment: @zzy " how a about the solution without boost" C++11 has both `shared_ptr` and `thread` in std (memory and thread headers respectively).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Sorry, I'm wondering solutions without `shard_ptr`.

Comment: @zzy make `MyClass` instanced obtainable only as pointers (hide the constructor, use a static method to create new instances). Implement the 'stopProcessing' flag. Make the thread function receive such a `MyClass` pointer, stop and _delete the received `MyClass` pointer_ if the flag is raised. You will need to implement the flag as atomic and use it as such up on both sides (processing thread and joining thread), otherwise you risk memory leaks (see [atomic_flag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_flag/) )

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a `stopProcessing` flag (make it atomic) as a member of `MyClass` and in your `ThreadFunc` method check at each cycle if this flag is set?

[EDIT: making clearer the answer]
There a two orthogonal problems:

1. stopping the processing (I lost my patience, stop now please). This can be arranged by setting a flag into `MyClass` and make `ThreadFunc` checking it as often as reasonable possible
2. deallocation of resources. This is best by using RAII - one example being the use of shared_ptr

Better keep them as separate concerns.

Combining them in a single operation may be possible, but risky.

E.g. if using shared_ptr, the once the joining thread decided "I had enough", it simply goes out of the block which keeps its "copy" of shared_ptr, thus the `shared_ptr::use_count` gets decremented. The thread function may notice this and decide to interpret it as an "caller had enough" and cut short the processing.
However, this implies that, in the future releases, nobody else (but the two threads) may acquire a `shared_ptr`, otherwise the "contract" of 'decremented `use_count` means abort' is broken.

(a `use_count==1` condition may still be usable - interpretation "Only me, the processing thread, seems to be interested in the results; no consumer for them, better abort the work").

Comment: Would `stopProcessing` be destroyed by destructor ?

Comment: @zzy - what I'm proposing is to decouple the interruption of the processing from the destruction. Why would one want to use "destruction of an object" as a signal for "stop the processing, I waited too long"?